# how to manipulate chrome tcp response

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a TCP client. For small response package, it works well. I have a issue when the response is on different packages (chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener called multiple times). They sometimes arrive in the right order and sometimes the variable 'index' makes no sense. How do you deal with it in javascript?

```
var index = 0, 
    effectiveSize = 0, 
    expectedLength = 0, 
    buf = [];

chrome.sockets.tcp.send(socketId, data, function(sendInfo) {});
chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
    effectiveSize += info.data.byteLength;

    if (index === 0) {
        offset = 0;
        readBuffer(info.data, 4); // header
        expectedLength = readBuffer(info.data, 4);
    }

    console.log('index: ' + index + ' expectedLength: ' + expectedLength + ' effectiveSize: ' + effectiveSize);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing some parenthesis....

Comment: Aside from the missing parentheses, What logs format are you expecting and what are you actually getting?